# Flashdevelop - Disable autocomplete for txt files

Tags: autocomplete, flashdevelop

I would like to turn off autocompletion for editing txt files (the syntax setting `Text`) in FlashDevelop 4.2.2 - how do I achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In **Settings** > **BasicCompletion** > **Disable Auto Completion**, set the value to `True`.

[image: Screenshot of Flashdevelop]