# How to stop FlashDevelop suggestions in text files

Tags: autocomplete, flashdevelop, haxe

I'm using FlashDevelop 4.6.1.30 in Windows, using it with HaxeFlixel.

The autocomplete suggestions appear when editing code - this is wanted, it is good.
They also appear when editing text files though - this is not wanted, it is not good.

Specifically, if I create a new text file in flash develop (so the file is called "readme.txt" or something), after typing a few words, FD tries to "guess" what I'm typing and pops up the suggestions list. This, of course, makes no sense when trying to type out things that aren't code.

Yes, I've seen this [Flashdevelop - Disable autocomplete for txt files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14124172/flashdevelop-disable-autocomplete-for-txt-files) and no, it doesn't work - even after a restart.

Here is a screenshot showing it not working...

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can confirm, setting that option doesn't prevent completion in `.txt` files. Consider [opening an issue on the FlashDevelop repository.](https://github.com/fdorg/flashdevelop?source=cc)

Comment: Opened an issue on the bug tracker https://github.com/fdorg/flashdevelop/issues/265

Answer (score 0):

Looks like a bug.

For now you can simply disable the BasicCompletion plugin (check Disable and restart FlashDevelop).